# How can I use single quotes with nested calls to eval()?

Tags: php, eval

I am trying to use single quotes with nested calls to `eval()`:

```
eval('eval(\'echo 'hi\';\');');
```

However, this triggers the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'hi' (T_STRING)

How can I use single quotes and resolve this error?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: You have a quote escaping issue—it works if you use `"hi"` instead of `'hi'`: `eval('eval(\'echo "hi";\');');`. But I concur with @JohnConde, I am a bit puzzled as to why you do that

Comment: @DarraghEnright Thanks... problem solved! but how i use single quote?

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue escaping single-quotes. You may use double quotes instead—`"hi"` instead of `'hi'`:

```
eval('eval(\'echo "hi";\');');
```

If you need to use single quotes, the backslashes that escape the single quotes will themselves need to be escaped, with a pair of additional backslashes (`\\`); i.e:

```
eval('eval(\'echo \\\'hi\\\';\');');
```

This yields:

> hi

As you can imagine, this will get messy quickly as the level of nesting increases.

It's worth noting that `eval()` is considered to be dangerous and you should only use it in very deliberate circumstances where you have thoroughly evaluated that there is no risk in using it, and there are no better ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

As stated in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> **Caution** The `eval()` language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

It's worth searching Stack Overflow for some [discussion on its usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).

Hope this helps :)